# SwiftUIでFirestoreに2次元配列を保存する方法について

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

**質問内容**
Firestoreに2次元配列を保存し、保存後に１次元配列を追加するサンプルプログラムを作りたいのですが、以下のエラーに対処できません。対処方法について、アドバイスいただけないでしょうか。

まず、エラー文は以下の画像の通りで、"Nested Arrays are not supported" とあります。
これはつまり、2次元配列は保存できないよ　という意味でしょうか。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

私が以下のテストコードでやりたかったことは、以下の通りです。
新規保存ボタンでは、　workername: [[sh, sm, eh, em]]  を保存
追加ボタンでは、　　　workername:  [sh, sm, eh, em]   をを追加し、
workername: [[sh, sm, eh, em],[sh, sm, eh, em]]   というデータする

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

**テストコード**

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseFirestore

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var name = ""
    @State var sh = ""
    @State var sm = ""
    @State var eh = ""
    @State var em = ""
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Group {
                TextField("氏名を入力", text: $name)
                TextField("S時", text: $sh)
                TextField("S分", text: $sm)
                TextField("E時", text: $eh)
                TextField("E分", text: $em)
            }
            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Button(action: {
                let db = Firestore.firestore()
                db.collection("collectionnameX").document("docmentnameX").setData([
                    name: [[sh, sm, eh, em]]
                
                ]) { err in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        print("Document successfully written!")
                    }
                }
            }){
                Text("新規保存")
                    .border(Color.red, width: 1)
            }
            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Button(action: {
                let db = Firestore.firestore()
                db.collection("collectionnameX").document("docmentnameX").updateData([
                    name: FieldValue.arrayUnion([sh, sm, eh, em])
                ]) { err in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        print("Document successfully written!")
                    }
                }
            }){
                Text("追加")
                    .border(Color.red, width: 1)
            }
            
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> まず、エラー文は以下の画像の通りで、"Nested Arrays are not supported" とあります。

Firebaseの公式ドキュメントに明記されているようです。

[データ型](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types?hl=ja#data_types)

> 配列の要素として他の配列値を格納することはできません。

ネストされた配列と言うのは、あなたがおっしゃるところの「二次元配列」になりますが、そのようなものを格納することはできない、と言うことですね。

---

仕様上は許されていても、「何番目はどんな意味を持つ」と言うことが決まっているデータを配列にしてしまうのは、データ設計上も好ましいものではありません。マップ(いわゆる辞書型)の配列は許されているようなので、そちらを使用すると言うのが一つの手でしょう。

新規保存:

```
        db.collection("collectionnameX").document("docmentnameX").setData([
            name: [["sh": sh, "sm": sm, "eh": eh, "em": em]]
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error writing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully written!")
            }
        }
```

追加:

```
        db.collection("collectionnameX").document("docmentnameX").updateData([
            name: FieldValue.arrayUnion([["sh": sh, "sm": sm, "eh": eh, "em": em]])
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error writing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully written!")
            }
        }
```

Comment: 度々、ありがとうございます。リンクまでつけていただき恐縮です。　仮にドキュメントの内容を把握していたとして、配列の要素が辞書型であればOKだとは気付けなかっただろうと思います。とても助かりました。

Comment: ちなみに、回答いただいた方法で対応できそうですが、関連して教えていただきたいことがあります。　ご回答いただいた方法以外で対応するとしたら、一旦Firestoreの"collectionnameX"-"docmentnameX"に保存されているデータを全削除し、更新した配列を保存するという方法もアリでしょうか？

Comment: @Mitty さん、一つのドキュメントのプロパティは基本全入れ替えになるので、「データを全削除し」の部分は不要のはずです。配列の内容をSwift側のコードで更新し、そのプロパティをストレートに更新(`FieldValue.arrayUnion`のような追加のための特殊な値は使わない)すればOKです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Swift側で更新したデータを、同じ場所に保存するという方法がシンプルで良さそうですね。